# Problem with bibliography entry due to dash and or brackets

Tags: biblatex, unicode

I have a biblatex entry which I cannot handle. It looks as follows:

```
@article{testentry,
    author = {Stevens, Jim (May) and Win, Zhang, K. Lo},
    title = {The e-approach to Understanding things},
    journal = {Journal of Research},
    volume = {12},
    number = {122},
    pages = {12-13},
    year = {1994}
}
```

I am using:

```
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
```

and

```
\usepackage[style=authoryear, 
backend=biber, 
giveninits=true,
uniquelist = false]{biblatex}
```

The generated output messes up the brackets of "(May)" in the author field, as well as the space before "e-approach". Error that I get: Unicode character U+2002 (inputenc) not set up for use with Latex.

What can I do to fix this?

Comment: U+2002 is an en space. Check your bib if you have used this and remove it. Alternatively you can define it with \DeclareUnicodeCharacter.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Thanks. How can I find the "en space"? I know that the issue is this specific entry, because when I remove it, the document compiles without problems.

Comment: well the problem with spaces is that they are not really visible ;-). On windows I would use e.g. babelpad to check for such input. I see one directly after the The of the title.

Comment: It's the space between `The` and `e-approach`. You can paste your `.bib` entry to https://w3c.github.io/xml-entities/unicode-names.html and search for `2002`. The other debugging solution is to add `\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{2002}{XXX Hello, here I am YYY}` to your preamble and then search for XXX in your document.

Comment: Thanks. I found the space and removed it. Now only the problem with the brackets remains "(May)"

Comment: The name `Jim (May) and Win, Zhang, K. Lo` looks a bit unusual. Biber parses it with the normal rules, which means that in `Jim (May)` `(May)` is treated as the family name and `Jim` as the given name (just as in `Emma Sigfridsson` `Emma` is the given name and `Sigfridsson` the family name). The first name is reversed in the bibliography, so you get `(May), James`. (Just as you would get "Sigfridsson, Emma" if she is first author.)

Comment: `Win, Zhang, K. Lo` is not technically syntactically malformed, but will be parsed as a single name consisting of a family name part `Win`, given name part `K. Lo` and suffix part ("junior part") `Zhang`. This may or may not be desired or an accurate representation of the actual name(s) involved.

Comment: Sorry my bad. In the creation of this example, I forgot to add a last name. I added "Stevens" now as last name. So this part in brackets is supposed to be a middle name. In my output, I do not see it at all. It comes as "(", so the "May)" is cut off.

Comment: Ah, then it's different. I'll write up an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [Ulrike Fischer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/2388/ulrike-fischer) says in the comments U+2002 is an en-space, so one of your spaces is not a normal space (U+0020), but an en-space (U+2002). From the wrong output (a space is missing between "The" and "e-appraoach" making the title read "Thee-approach") you can already guess where the problem might be and you can verify that by [pasting your `.bib` entry](https://w3c.github.io/xml-entities/unicode-names.html?@article%7Btestentry,%0A%20%20%20%20author%20=%20%7BJim%20(May)%20and%20Win,%20Zhang,%20K.%20Lo%7D,%0A%20%20%20%20title%20=%20%7BThe%E2%80%82e-approach%20to%20Understanding%20things%7D,%0A%20%20%20%20journal%20=%20%7BJournal%20of%20Research%7D,%0A%20%20%20%20volume%20=%20%7B12%7D,%0A%20%20%20%20number%20=%20%7B122%7D,%0A%20%20%20%20pages%20=%20%7B12-13%7D,%0A%20%20%20%20year%20=%20%7B1994%7D%0A%7D) to https://w3c.github.io/xml-entities/unicode-names.html. The output of that tool shows

```
  U+0054 LATIN CAPITAL LETTER T     T
  U+0068 LATIN SMALL LETTER H     h
  U+0065 LATIN SMALL LETTER E     e
  U+2002 EN SPACE     &ensp; \hspace{0.6em}
  U+0065 LATIN SMALL LETTER E     e
  U+002d HYPHEN-MINUS     -
  U+0061 LATIN SMALL LETTER A     a
  U+0070 LATIN SMALL LETTER P     p
  U+0070 LATIN SMALL LETTER P     p
  U+0072 LATIN SMALL LETTER R     r
  U+006f LATIN SMALL LETTER O     o
  U+0061 LATIN SMALL LETTER A     a
  U+0063 LATIN SMALL LETTER C     c
  U+0068 LATIN SMALL LETTER H     h
```

where you can clearly see that the problematic U+2002 is after the `The`.

Another debugging technique for issues like this is to add a `\DeclareUnicodeCharacter` with an easily searchable replacement text to your preamble

```
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{2002}{XXX Hello, here I am ???}
```

Then you can just search for "XXX" in your output document to find the problematic position.

The solution here is simple, delete the en-space and replace it with a normal space so that your title reads

```
title   = {The e-approach to Understanding things},
```

---

The `author` field contains two interesting names.

`Win, Zhang, K. Lo` is not *technically* syntactically malformed, but will be parsed as a single name consisting of

- a family name part `Win`,
- given name part `K. Lo` and
- suffix part ("junior part") `Zhang`.

This may or may not be desired or an accurate representation of the actual name(s) involved. Normally the suffix is only used for "Jr."/"Sr."/"III.".

---

The problem with `Stevens, Jim (May)` only becomes apparent if you request given name initials with `giveninits=true,`.

The name is parsed as

- family name `Stevens` and
- given name `Jim (May)`

when given name initials are generated, Biber just takes the first character of each "word", so we end up with `J. (.` which is less then ideal. In cases like this it is probably best to give the desired given name initials manually with `given-i` in Biber's extended name format.

```
author = {family=Stevens, given={Jim (May)}, given-i=J},
```

---

In total

```
\documentclass[british]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage[style=authoryear, giveninits=true, backend=biber]{biblatex}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@article{testentry,
  author  = {family=Stevens, given={Jim (May)}, given-i=J
             and Win, Zhang, K. Lo},
  title   = {The e-approach to Understanding things},
  journal = {Journal of Research},
  volume  = {12},
  number  = {122},
  pages   = {12-13},
  year    = {1994}
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}


\begin{document}
\cite{testentry}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: Stevens, J. and K. L. Win Zhang (1994). ‘The e-approach to Understanding things’. In: Journal of Research 12.122, pp. 12–13.]

Comment: very interesting thank you. Could you explain what `given-i=J` is for?

Comment: @ghx If given `given-i` will manually override the otherwise automatically generated given name initial. Since the automatic initial would be "J. (." we override it so we just get "J." (of course you can do anything here, you could say `given-i={J. M.}` if you like).