# Encoding error in LaTeX - all umlauts, etc. are correctly presented

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, unicode

Suffering with compilation using TeXMaker. I added an external .bib file to add to my thesis, and the resulting changes give me the following error upon compilation (PdFLaTeX + quick view):

```
! Package inputenc Error: Unicode character ̈ (U+0308)(inputenc) not set up for use with LaTeX.See the inputenc package documentation for explanation.Type H <return> for immediate help....
```

Strangely enough, the resulting PDF is built in my directory with no visible issues.. any clue what is going on? I have made sure to encode any umlauts, etc. correctly in my bibliography file (e.g. as `{\"u}`, etc.).

Comment: This is likely a case in which a "weird invisible character" is in your bib file, probably from copying and pasting internet stuff (e. g. author names, title of books, abstracts). **Proposal:** Remove each citation one by one until you find the problem-causing entry (entries).

Comment: For further help, I suggest you create an MWE following this post: https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4407

Comment: I think that's the ticket - thanks Dr. Kuehner. Tedious but necessary work!

Comment: U+308 is COMBINING DIAERESIS ... So look for a stray umlaut, and perhaps not your regular äöü one ...

Comment: I don't use TeXMaker, so I don't know if this is actually possible, but with the editor I do use (emacs), it's possible to "pick up" the reported character from the log, then use it as a search argument in the file.  (It's not even necessary to know what the offending character is or means; a match is unambiguous proof.)  This is very much quicker than the "divide and conquer" method, although if the search attempt fails, "divide and conquer" is still available.

Comment: You could try something like `\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{0308}{XXX HERE I AM XXX}`. This will suppress the error and will make the "XXX HERE I AM XXX" appear in the document where the offending character appeared. This should help you find the problematic passage/`.bib` entry.

Comment: @moewe That's super smart. You should convert this to an answer.

Comment: See also https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/552489/35864

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*(Converting Comment to Answer)*

- This is likely a case in which a **"weird invisible character"** is in your bib file, probably from **copying and pasting stuff from the internet** (e. g. author names, title of books, abstracts).
- **Proposal:** Remove each citation one by one until you find the problem-causing entry (entries).

Answer (score 3):

One simple way to find out which entry is responsible for the error is to give the Unicode character in question a definition that can easily be searched for in the output. For example something like

```
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{0308}{XXX HERE I AM XXX ???}
```

Then search for "XXX" or "???" in the resulting PDF. (Keep in mind that some PDF readers may have problem finding words if they are hyphenated. So I usually prefer stuff like "XXX" and "???" that is unusual enough and will probably not be hyphenated.)

A common issue with Biber and non-ASCII characters are constructions involving (dotless) is (the letter i without a dot). See [Unicode -(U+301) error in biblatex, but not in main text: {\'{\i}}](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/469555/35864). So if I were you, I'd probably look for that first. Maybe you have `\"{\i}` somewhere in your `.bib` file. For Biber that should be `\"{i}` or even better just `ï`.

Comment: +1: I took the liberty of adding a small modification.